# PHP PDO dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a simple function that returns a count from a database table, based on some criteria.

```
function MyCount($strTable, $strCriteria) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $strTable . " ";
    if (trim($strCriteria) != "") $strSQL .= "WHERE " . $strCriteria;
    $results = mysql_query($strSQL, $objConn);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    return $row[0];
}
```

Its very useful for quickly getting a value in 1 line of code, e.g:

```
$Users = MyCount("Users", "Deleted = 0");
```

However, I'm now trying to move to PDO and am having trouble passing in the were as parametrized values. I'm trying to do something like the below (which doesn't work):

```
$objQuery=$objConn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as TheCount FROM :table_name WHERE :criteria");
$objQuery->bindParam(':table_name', $strTable);
$objQuery->bindParam(':criteria', $strCriteria);
```

I guess the obvious would be:

```
$objQuery=$objConn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as TheCount FROM :table_name WHERE ".$strCriteria");
$objQuery->bindParam(':table_name', $strTable);
```

But, this seems to go against the spirit of parametrized values... does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can you not add an extra parameter to the function, $Users = MyCount("TABLE","CRITERIA","VALUE"); then you can check with PDO with ...WHERE $CRITERIA = :VALUE and then bind the value?

Comment: Nice idea, but the flexibility of the other method was that I could pass in more complecx queries - e.g. Deleted=0 AND (Email='' OR Phone='')

Comment: its good that you're switching to a better extension, anyway, you can bind table names and column names, you can only whitelist input there

Comment: @Ghost: that's supposed to read "you can __not__ bind table names..."

Comment: @DanMan sorry just a typo, yes i meant `cannot`, excuse for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the issue:

```
$objQuery->bindParam(':table_name', $strTable);
```

You can only bind values ( `field= :value`) in `PDO` you **cannot** bind table names or column names or custom dynamic where clause.

So you just build the query manually:

```
SELECT count(*) as TheCount FROM `$strTable` WHERE $strCriteria
```

---

```
function my_count($strTable, $strCriteria, $objConn)
{
    $sql ="SELECT count(*) as TheCount FROM $strTable WHERE $strCriteria";
    $objQuery=$objConn->query($sql);
    $row =$objQuery->fetch();

    return $row['TheCount'];
}


$Users = my_count("Users", "Deleted = 0",  $objConn);
```

Comment: This is what I thought... but I didn't know about the table names, so thanks for that.