# PHP PDO with dynamically created where statements

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to convert mysqli_query to PDO.

I got stuck with my dynamically created WHERE clausule.
I read this post ([PHP PDO dynamic WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697050/php-pdo-dynamic-where-clause)), but there you lose the prepare function of PDO, and that is what I want to do.

This is (part of) my origional code

```
// this is the '$_POST' array
$_POST['org'][0] = 1;
$_POST['org'][1] = 2;
$_POST['org'][2] = 5;

/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql['select'] = "SELECT * FROM `table` ";

if(isset($_POST['org']) AND count($_POST['org']) > 0) {  
  $sql['where'] .= "WHERE ( `org_id` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['org'][0])."' ";

  foreach ($_POST['org'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key !== 0)
      $sql['where'] .= "OR `org_id` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value)."' ";
  }
}

$sql = $sql['select'] . $sql['where'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

How can I use prepared statements in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your query and instead of using values inside the query you should use placeholders (`?` or `:placeholder_name`):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (?,?,?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($_POST['org']);
```

Go and read https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples for more examples

Answer (score 1):

Ah!

This is what I did now, and it works. Thanks.

```
$sql['where'] .= "WHERE ( `org_id` = ? ";
$values[] = $_POST['org'][0];

foreach ($_POST['org'] as $key => $value) {
  if($key !== 0) {
    $sql['where'] .= "OR `org_id` = ? ";
    $values[] = $value;
  }
}

$sql['where'] .= ")";

$sql = $sql['select'] . $sql['where'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute((array) $values);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Technically true but using named placeholders and building an associative array makes this a lot more flexible and is only slightly more work.

Comment: a note on style:  my preference is to include the required leading space before the `WHERE` or `OR` along with the keyword, rather than requiring preceding code to include an extra trailing space at the end. e.g. `.= " WHERE ...`  and `.= " OR ...`   Just makes more sense to me. When looking at the code that sets up the first part of the select, it's not at all obvious why a trailing space is needed.But looking at the code that appends the WHERE, its more obvious why there needs to be space before the WHERE keyword,... seems like we should do it there, rather than backtrack to other code

Comment: @tadman what do you mean? Can you give a little example of that?

Comment: If you use named placeholders that match your args, you can just `execute($_POST)` or `execute($_POST['org']`) or whatever. You should also consider `org_id IN (?, ?, ...)` instead of `org_id=? OR org_id=? OR ...`. The answer by d0niek incorporates both these elements.